# Employee Effort tracker using python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to create one excel sheet which contains all the employee weekly efforts. For that, employees need to fill the form that input will directly store in the excel sheet. Once everyone is finished I need to get that automatically filled excel sheet. Is it possible in python? Please can someone guide me on this how to proceed...

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far and the result expected with some examples.

Comment: Google forms lets you save form data to a Google spreadsheet. No coding required. But if you want to do this with Python, you can look at the csv module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. Also, Stack Overflow is only for help when you run into problems with your code, so this question doesn't really belong here.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, try to show some code to prove you've tried first.

You could start will building the data structure you want for your application. Like

`Name | Hours Spent for this week | Current Time`

Then, you can use

`import csv`

to create a csv file to do so.

CSV module is impleted in python, there is also an excel one, but I highly recommend CSV, because it is easier to be processed by other programs.